# Consider the following code fragment. Suppose that A[0...n] is an array whose elements are natural numbers between 0 and n

Tags: algorithm

My first post in stackoverflow, I'm having trouble with this question regarding algorithms.

Consider the following code fragment. Suppose that A[0...n] is an array whose elements are natural numbers between 0 and n.

```
    for i=0 to n-1 do {
        for j=n-i-1 to 0 do{
            if(A[j] <= A[j+1]){
               print A[j]-A[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
```

(a) As  a   function    of  n,  what    is  the maximum number  of  times   that    the print   statement   might   be
executed?   What    is  the pattern of  entries in  A   that    leads   to  this    worst-case? Express your    answer  as  a   summation,  and then    express the solution    to  this    summation   as  an  exact   (not    asymptotic) 
formula involving   n.

(b) As  a   function    of  n,  what    is  the minimum number  of  times   that    the output  statement   might   be  executed?   What    is  the pattern of  entries in  A   that    leads   to  this    best-case?  For this    part,   you may 
express your    answer  asymptotically.

For A, I have the pattern of entries as 1,2,3,...,n-1

Giving me f-(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1=O(n^2)

For B, I think that the minimum amount of executions could be zero if the conditions are unsatisfied, but not sure how else to proceed.

I'm unsure about both parts and would greatly appreciate explanations/assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is the part we need to determine when the print-statement will be executed:

```
if(A[j] <= A[j+1]){
    print A[j]-A[j+1];
}
```

So the print-statement will be executed whenever we encounter two consecutive values such that the value with smaller index will be smaller than the one with the larger index. So for any ascendingly ordered array the print-statement will be executed for every `j`, if it's ordered descendingly never.

Together with the specifications for the array this leads to the arrays

```
worstcase = [0, 1, 2, ..., n]
bestcase = [n, n-1, n-2, ..., 0]
```

Now in the worstcase the print-statement will be executed always, so:

```
result = 0;
for i=0 to n-1 do {
    for j=n-i-1 to 0 do{
        result += 1;
    }
}
```

(`result` counts the number of times print would be executed) which is obviously equivalent to:

```
result = 0;
for i=0 to n-1 do {
    result += n - i;
}
```

Or

```
result = 0;
for i=1 to n do{
    result += i;
}
```

So `result = (n + 1)*n/2` which would be `O(n^2)`.

Now in the worst-case we can apply the same pattern:

```
result = 0;
for i=0 to n-1 do {
    for j=n-i-1 to 0 do{
        result += 0;
    }
}
```

Which can be obviously reduced to `result = 0`, which is `O(1)`. Usually this would be expressed in a more mathematical way, but since I'm not exactly a pro with latex, you'll have to think of the summation-signs yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance and explanations!

Comment: @TweezerCube glad to help ;) If this answer solved your question, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)